# How can I execute some code while a view is pressed (held down) Android

Tags: java, android

I'm writing a small app and I need to run some code while the user holds down a screen button, an ImageView to be more precise. I have tried with onTouchEvent, but the code only executes in an actual event (down, up or move).

I would like my code to execute while I hold the button down. Any idea on how to do this?

---

This is what I tried

```
myImageView.setOnLongClickListener (new OnLongClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View view) 
            {
                Log.i("TAG","FOO");
                return true;
            }
        });
```

What I want is for FOO to be printed over and over while I hold down the button/screen.

Comment: Can you please paste the code you tried yet.

Answer (score 2):

Or you can do like this:

```
public class myActivity extends Activity implements OnTouchListener {


private ImageView iv = null;


@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

    int a = event.getAction();

    if (v == iv)
    {
        if (a == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
            handleDown();
        else if (a == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)
            handleUp();
    }

    return true;
}

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.myLayout);

    iv = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.iv0);

    // . . . 

}

// . . .
```